# Generate daterange and insert in a new column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

**Problem statement:** Create a dataframe with multiple columns and populate one column with daterange series of 5 minute interval.

**Tried solution:**

1. Created a dataframe initially with just one row / 5 columns (all "NAN") .
2. **Command used to generate daterange:**

   ```
   rf = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=5, freq='5min').
   ```

   **O/P of rf :**

   ```
   DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 00:05:00',
                  '2000-01-01 00:10:00', '2000-01-01 00:15:00',
                  '2000-01-01 00:20:00'],
                   dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5T')
   ```
3. When I try to assign rf to one of the columns of df (df['column1'] = rf)., it is throwing exception as shown below (copying the last line of exception).

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2879, in _sanitize_index
       raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   ```

Though I understood the issue, I don't know the solution. I'm looking for a easy way to achieve this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston : Basically I am trying to build data (with multiple rows/columns) by injecting predictive randomness in each column. I have a dictionary with all "NAN" for each key . Created a dataframe using this dictionary . Hence, created dataframe was of Just one row and multiple columns. Now, I want to program each column to have random data which follow definite pattern. This is the problem that I want to address.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston. How can I get similar O/P with out date_range as index and only integers (starting from 0,1,..) as index ??

Comment: With the above dataframe, five rows/columns were created and now if we want to put the date_range in to one of the columns (each row will have a date and next row will have difference of 5 minutes under same column).,getting the below mentioned issue.                                
d1['E']= pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=150000, freq='5T')
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" . If I do d1['E'][0] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=150000, freq='5T')., all date ranges get into row 0. Either way not getting desired O/P. How can I feed date_range to each row ??

Answer (score 2):

I think, I was slowly understanding the power/usage of dataframes.

- Initially create a dataframe :

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100),columns=['A','B','C'])
  ```
- Then created a date_range.

  ```
  date = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=100, freq='5T')
  ```
- Using "assign" function , added date_range as new column to already created dataframe (df).

  ```
  df = df.assign(D=date)
  ```

**Final O/P of df:**

```
df[:5]

 A    B    C                   D
 0  NaN  NaN  NaN 2000-01-01 00:00:00

 1  NaN  NaN  NaN 2000-01-01 00:05:00

 2  NaN  NaN  NaN 2000-01-01 00:10:00

 3  NaN  NaN  NaN 2000-01-01 00:15:00

 4  NaN  NaN  NaN 2000-01-01 00:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe has only one row and you try to insert data for five rows.

Comment: Exactly. In order to address this., can you tell me the optimal way ? Can't I dynamically increase the rows of a dataframe such that . particular column will have data (in my case ., it is daterange)and other columns will have "NAN" ??